# How to rasterize a vector dataset in R?

Tags: raster, shapefile, r

I would like to compare vector vs raster data. So i try to fix a problem using both ways.

I made it in vector first :

```
coastline<-readShapeSpatial("shp")
wets<-readShapeSpatial("shp")
wetb<-gBuffer(wets,width=500,byid=T) #doing a buffer of 500m of the wetlands
wetb2<-gBuffer(wets,width=1000,byid=T) #doing abuffer of 1000
wetb1$vat=0 # assigning a new column of 0 in the buffer i created
wetb2$vat=5 # assigning a new column of 5 in the second buffer
coastline$vat=10 #assigning a new column of 10 in the rest of the land
```

Now how would i write the same thing in raster?

My thoughts are that i should turn the coastline and the wetlands into raster first off.How would i do that and what after that?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here - what do you mean by 'test vector vs raster'? Your code is uncommented and thus it's impossible to figure out why you're assigning various vectors ... if you want to do these steps with rasters, are you looking to do buffer operations?

Comment: I want to compare the two types (vector vs raster) by doing the same procedure, once with vector and once with raster.i will edit my main question and add comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

```
# Use rgdal, better library
library(rgdal)
coastline <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="coastline")
wets <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="wets")
```

Rasterize 'em:

```
require(raster)
# Create a generic raster, set the extent to the same as wetlands
r.raster <- raster()
```

Use extent (from raster package) to read bounds of vector and assign to the raster:

```
extent(r.raster) <- extent(wets)
res(r.raster) <- 2500 # set cell size to 2500 metres

# Make a raster of the wetlands:
coastline.r <- rasterize(wets, r.raster)

# Do the same buffering operation but in raster:
wetb <- buffer(wets, width=500)
```

If you want to do it by individual features, you could loop through them and create a raster stack layer for each feature.

Comment: Can you also provide an example of how to perform the buffer part and and assign procedure like the question.Because documentation of the package isn;t that easy.Also add comments on how you used the extents previously.

Comment: Updated code with comments on `extent()` and corrected missing `buffer()` command.

Comment: Nice.why the raster()? what the empty parenthesis supposed to mean? and also i did the buffer part like that and it returned this warning : Warning message:
In couldBeLonLat(x) :
  raster has a longitude/latitude CRS, but coordinates do not match that

Comment: `raster()` creates an empty raster object, which can then have arbitrary resolution (`res()`) and bounds (`extent()`) assigned. The warning you see lets you know that your data might be in lat/lon - i.e. degrees - instead of a projected system where buffer width actually means something.

Comment: do u know how to turn it into a projected system in R so it can recieve the buffer normally. Thnx for the help

Comment: Search for "[r] [raster] project" here on GIS.se - and don't forget to upvote good questions and answers you find!

Comment: I tried on another shp and it worked well,just with this one appears to have this difficulty.Any other ideas? tried the conversion to UTM but didn't work.

Comment: The one with the warning about lat/lon probably has an incorrect .prj file assigned - from the sound of it the buffer works with metre widths, but that wouldn't be the case if it really were lat/lon. Delete the .prj and/or reassign the CRS and re-save.

Comment: This answer helped me immensely with a project where I am looking to combine a raster of landcover with a streetmap shapefile. I had the disappearing map problem too and have been iterating over the answer with much success. Thank you @Simbamangu

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new package [fasterize](https://rdrr.io/cran/fasterize/man/fasterize.html#heading-2) to speed up the conversion between polygons (here using `sf` object) to raster. From the polygon first you need to create normal raster to define desired resolution, and than fill in values from polygon.

Here is whole example ([available here](https://rdrr.io/cran/fasterize/man/fasterize.html#heading-2)):

Read packages:

```
library(sf)
library(fasterize)
```

Create polygons:

```
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p1 <- list(p1, hole)
p2 <- list(rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0)))
p3 <- list(rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0)))
pols <- st_sf(value = rep(1,3),
              geometry = st_sfc(lapply(list(p1, p2, p3), st_polygon)))
```

Create first raster with desired resolution:

```
r <- raster(pols, res = 1)
```

Rasterize `sf` polygon using `fasterize` function:

```
r <- fasterize(pols, r, field = "value", fun="sum")
plot(r)
```